# cassandra local_quorum query is inconsistent

Tags: cassandra

cassandra version: 2.1.15

Number of nodes: dc1: 80, dc2: 80

problem:

Our copy strategy is as follows:

```
WITH REPLICATION = {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy','dc1': 3,'dc2': 3};
```

We encountered a problem with Cassandra, and it was inconsistent when querying with local_quorum. We will only read and write in dc1.
We also use local_quorum for writing, and then use local_quorum for queries.

But there is a phenomenon, use the following statement:

```
select count from table where partitionKey=?
```

The results of the query were initially inconsistent and eventually consistent.

Assuming that the first is 10000, the second is 9998, and the third is 9997, it may remain at 10001 in the end(Maybe it was triggered to read repair, which led to the final stabilization) .
During this period, we have done a large-scale expansion. And make sure that every machine is cleaned up. And we also found that the results of using getEndpoint    on different machines are inconsistent. In the end, we found that the result of getEndpoint has 4 machines in dc1.

Then we executed getSstable on the corresponding 4 machines, only 3 machines showed the results, and the other machine did not show the results. At the same time, we encountered a similar problem with another partitionKey, but this partitionKey was only queried once, because we recorded the total number of partitionKey in another place, and we can confirm that the total number of partitionKey is incorrect.

After we restarted each machine of dc1 one by one, this problem was solved.
The total number of partitionKey is consistent with the result recorded by us, and if the same query is done multiple times, the result will not change.
Therefore, I suspect that the gossip synchronization node information is too slow, which may lead to inconsistent final results when selecting nodes for query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there may be a few things going on here.  I'll agree that it was likely due to the expansion of the cluster.

> The results of the query were initially inconsistent and eventually consistent.

Cassandra 2.1 still allows for each table to have a configured read repair chance, and the default value is 10%.  So given enough retries, a read repair will be triggered and inconsistent values will repair themselves.

> Then we executed getSstable on the corresponding 4 machines, only 3 machines showed the results, and the other machine did not show the results. At the same time, we encountered a similar problem with another partitionKey, but this partitionKey was only queried once, because we recorded the total number of partitionKey in another place, and we can confirm that the total number of partitionKey is incorrect.

Not exactly sure what happened there, but it sounds like one or more new nodes had trouble joining and something may have been messed up during the token allocation process.  My guess is that one or more original nodes had token range maps (in `system.peers`) which were incorrect or inconsistent with what the other nodes could see.  Good to know that was straightened out with a restart.

Recommendations:

- **Upgrade**.  If you can't get off of Cassandra 2.1, at least get on [2.1.19](https://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/2.2.19/).  It was released last November, and will have 2 years of bug fixes that you don't have now.
- **Build your node counts as a factor of your RF**.  With Cassandra versions prior to 3.0, the token allocation was a little flakey.  To help optimize it, the number of nodes should allow the RF to evenly balance-out.  In your case, 80 nodes per DC is *not* divisible by 3 (the RF).  So I would bump each DC up to 81.  And then run `cleanup`, of course.
- **Disable the dynamic snitch**.  The dynamic snitch leverages gossip to try and optimize reads to better-performing servers.  But, it generates a lot of noise, which unfortunately can slow things down due to making its observations.  It *may* be a contributing factor here.  Just set `dynamic_snitch:false`.

For more details on these tips and other info, I recommend two articles:

- Amy Tobey's [Cassandra 2.1 Administration Guide](https://tobert.github.io/pages/als-cassandra-21-tuning-guide.html)
- Jon Haddad's [14 Things To Do When Setting Up A New Cassandra Cluster](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2019/01/30/new-cluster-recommendations.html)